Connection string to read recordset from a table in Microsoft WORD
In Powerpoint, I'm writing VBA code to read data from different data source files. To get data from Excel, I have no problem creating a recordset by using a connection string as follows:
With cn
  .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
  .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & gSpreadsheetPathAndFileName & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
  .Open
  Set rs = .Execute(sql)
End With

My question is: is there any similar connection string code that will allow me to read a recordset from a table in a Microsoft Word document? If so, what is it? I have searched and searched for an answer, and cannot find anything that helps answer the question one way or the other.
I already know how to read the data from a Word table this way:
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(filePathAndName)
Set myTable = wdDoc.Tables(1)
For ppRow = 2 To myTable.Rows.count
  For ppCol = 1 To myTable.Columns.count
    [etc.]
  next
next

But that seems to be quite slow, and most importantly it doesn't easily allow me to create a SQL query, like
SELECT * FROM WORKSHEET$ WHERE LASTANAME = 'SMITH'
That's the reason I'd like to be able to use a SQL query to create a recordset when reading from WORD. Plus it would allow a common set of code for both Excel and Word, just changing the connection string.
Is it possible?
Thanks for any help.

I've never seen an ADO connection used with Word. Word doesn't have worksheets, cell ranges, etc.

Sure this is possible, after all it is only code so you can do (almost) everything. Have you checked if you have set the reference (under Extra's) to the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library? Or the same you use in your excel?

I do have a reference set to ActiveX Data Objects. The problem is that I have no idea what the connetion string should look like, or if it can be done at all.
